# Save selectlist value (taxonomy) in wp:wp_set_object_terms

Tags: plugins, php, custom-taxonomy, sanitization

In my admin for part i have additional fields (like price or brand - which is taxonomy). When i edit or create new part, i set up additional data.

and price saving is without any problem, but saving value from select list is something strange - it didn't save:

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $_POST['part_brand'], 'brands', true);
```

according to wp doc: this function update value from taxonomy select. But for me it didn't work.

All code you could see here:

http://pastebin.com/N4gZL3uN

how to save value from select list (taxonomy) in wp?

whole code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: parts
Plugin URI: http://wp.tutsplus.com/
Description: descr
Version: 1.0
Author: Me
Author URI: http://wp.tutsplus.com/
License: GPLv2
*/
add_action('init', 'part_init');

function part_init()
{
  $args = array(
    'label' => __('Parts') ,
    'labels' => array(
      'edit_item' => __('Edit Part') ,
      'add_new_item' => __('Add New Part') ,
      'view_item' => __('View Part') ,
    ) ,
    'singular_label' => __('Part') ,
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    '_builtin' => false,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array(
      "slug" => "parts"
    ) , // формат ссылок
    'supports' => array(
      'title',
      'editor',
      'thumbnail'
    )
  );
  register_post_type('part', $args);
  $labels_gr = array(
    'name' => 'Группы',
    'singular_name' => 'Группы',
    'search_items' => 'Поиск групп',
    'all_items' => 'Все группы',
    'parent_item' => 'Родительская группа',
    'parent_item_colon' => 'Родительская группа:',
    'edit_item' => 'Редактирование группы',
    'update_item' => 'Обновить группу',
    'add_new_item' => 'Добавить новую группу',
    'new_item_name' => 'Имя новой группы',
    'menu_name' => 'Группы',
  );
  $labels_brands = array(
    'name' => 'Бренды',
    'singular_name' => 'Бренд',
    'search_items' => 'Поиск брендов',
    'popular_items' => 'Популярные бренды',
    'all_items' => 'Все бренды',
    'edit_item' => 'Редактировать бренд',
    'update_item' => 'Обновить бренд',
    'add_new_item' => 'Добавить новый бренд',
    'new_item_name' => 'Имя нового бренда',
    'menu_name' => 'Бренды',
    'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Разделять бренды запятыми',
    'add_or_remove_items' => 'Добавить или удалить бренд',
    'choose_from_most_used' => 'Выберите бренд из наиболее используемых',
    'menu_name' => 'Бренды',
  );
  register_taxonomy('groups', 'post', array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels_gr,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'group'
    ) ,
  ));
  register_taxonomy('brands', 'post', array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => $labels_brands,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'brands'
    ) ,
  ));
}

function part_add_meta_box()
{
  add_meta_box('part_additional_fields', __('Дополнительные поля', 'part_textdomain') , 'part_meta_box_callback', 'part');
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'part_add_meta_box');

function part_meta_box_callback($post)
{
  wp_nonce_field('part_meta_box', 'part_meta_box_nonce');
  $part_weight = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'part_weight', true);

  // $part_brand = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'part_brand', true );

  $part_brand = get_terms('brands', 'hide_empty=0');
  $part_price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'part_price', true);
  $part_group = get_terms('groups', 'hide_empty=0');
  echo '<label for="part_weight">';
  _e('Вес', 'myplugin_textdomain');
  echo '</label> ';
  echo '<input id="part_weight" name="part_weight" value="' . esc_attr($part_weight) . '" size="25" type="number" />';
  echo "<br />";
?>
  <label for="part_brand">Бренд</label>
  <select name='part_brand' id='part_brand'>
          <option value=''
          <?php
  if (!count($part_brand)) echo "selected"; ?>>None</option>
          <?php
  foreach($part_brand as $brand)
  {
    if (!is_wp_error($part_brand) && !empty($part_brand) && !strcmp($brand->slug, $part_brand[0]->slug)) echo "<option value='" . $brand->slug . "' selected>" . $brand->name . "</option>\n";
    else echo "<option value='" . $brand->slug . "'>" . $brand->name . "</option>\n";
  }

?>
  </select>    
  <?php
  echo "<br />";
  echo '<label for="part_price">';
  _e('Цена', 'myplugin_textdomain');
  echo '</label> ';
  echo '<input id="part_price" name="part_price" value="' . esc_attr($part_price) . '" size="25" type="number" />';
  echo "<br />";
?>
  <label for="part_group">Группа</label>
  <select name='part_group' id='part_group'>
          <option value=''
          <?php
  if (!count($part_group)) echo "selected"; ?>>None</option>
          <?php
  foreach($part_group as $brand)
  {
    if (!is_wp_error($part_group) && !empty($part_group) && !strcmp($brand->slug, $part_group[0]->slug)) echo "<option value='" . $brand->slug . "' selected>" . $brand->name . "</option>\n";
    else echo "<option value='" . $brand->slug . "'>" . $brand->name . "</option>\n";
  }

?>
  </select>    
  <?php
}

function part_save_meta_box_data($post_id)
{
  if (!isset($_POST['part_meta_box_nonce']))
  {
    return;
  }

  if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['part_meta_box_nonce'], 'part_meta_box'))
  {
    return;
  }

  if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
  {
    return;
  }

  if (isset($_POST['post_type']) && 'part' == $_POST['post_type'])
  {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
    {
      return;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))
    {
      return;
    }
  }

  if (!isset($_POST['part_weight']) || !isset($_POST['part_weight']) || !isset($_POST['part_weight']) || !isset($_POST['part_group']))
  {
    return;
  }

  $part_weight_data = sanitize_text_field($_POST['part_weight']);

  // $part_brand_data = sanitize_option( $_POST['part_brand'], $_POST['part_brand']);

  wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $_POST['part_brand'], 'brands', true);
  $part_price_data = sanitize_text_field($_POST['part_price']);

  // $part_group = sanitize_option( $_POST['part_group'] );

  wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $_POST['part_group'], 'groups', true);

  // Update the meta field in the database.

  update_post_meta($post_id, 'part_weight', $part_weight_data);

  // update_post_meta( $post_id, 'part_brand', $part_brand_data );

  update_post_meta($post_id, 'part_price', $part_price_data);

  // update_post_meta( $post_id, 'part_group', $part_group );

}

add_action('save_post', 'part_save_meta_box_data');
?>
```

Comment: Please do not add outgoing links for code or other major parts of your question. If the link is dead, the question can't be understood anymore. Fix it with an [edit] and paste your code in the question.

Comment: @kaiser i edited it.

Comment: My original answer was wrong. `wp_set_object_terms` accepts slug as a valid parameter.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic so how to be ? ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it so:

```
$part_brand = get_terms('brands', 'hide_empty=0');
<label for="part_brand">Бренд</label>
  <select name='part_brand' id='part_brand'>
          <option value=''
          <?php
  **$brand_names = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'brands');**
  if (!count($brand_names)) echo "selected"; ?>>None</option>
          <?php
  foreach($part_brand as $brand)
  {
    if (!is_wp_error($brand_names) && !empty($brand_names) && !strcmp($brand->slug, $brand_names[0]->slug)) echo "<option value='" . $brand->slug . "' selected>" . $brand->name . "</option>\n";
    else echo "<option value='" . $brand->slug . "'>" . $brand->name . "</option>\n";
  }

?>
  </select>
```